# Second ViewController doesn't show the information when coming back to it

Tags: ios, swift

I have two View controllers emulating a spreadsheet with Cells, user inputs in TextFields, and there are calculated Cells to be shown in the two scenes.

Calculations are triggered by a calc button which gets user input from the Textfields and creates the instances of the Cells and any calculations.

Navigation between VCs is handled by Segue and there are UserDefaults functions for sending any data.

**The problem** is that TextField in Second View Controller Cell D5 is empty when you come to that VC for a Second time, while First View Controller is Ok, always showing the information. The Cell object in SecondVc Cell D5 was created and shown the first time but it is not shown the second time you visit it, but the object does exist.

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var C1ValueTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var C2ValueTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var C3ValueTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var C4ValueTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var C5ValueTextField: UITextField!


@IBAction func calc(_ sender: Any) {

    // Input C1
    let C1 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "C1", cellName: "", value: Int(C1ValueTextField.text!)!)
    C1.printCell()

    // Input C2
    let C2 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "C2", cellName: "", value: Int(C2ValueTextField.text!)!)
    C2.printCell()

    // calc C4
    let C4 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "C4", cellName: "", value: C1.value + C2.value)
    C4ValueTextField.text = String(C4.value)
    C4.printCell()


    Cell.saveCellsUserDefaults(cells: [C1, C2, C4])

}
```

// SecondTableViewController

```
class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var cells = Cell.getCellsUserDefaults()



@IBOutlet weak var D1ValueTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var D2ValueTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var D3ValueTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var D4ValueTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var D5ValueTextField: UITextField!


@IBAction func calc(_ sender: Any) {

    // D5 Problem: info disappears from TextField when navigating across VCs

    let D5 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "D5", cellName: "", value: Int(D5ValueTextField.text!)!)
    D5.printCell()

    Cell.saveCellsUserDefaults(cells: [D5])
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let cells = Cell.getCellsUserDefaults()



    // calc D1
    let D1 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "D1", cellName: "", value: cells[0].value)
    D1ValueTextField.text = String(D1.value)
    D1.printCell()


    // calc D2
    let D2 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "D2", cellName: "", value: cells[1].value)
    D2ValueTextField.text = String(D2.value)
    D2.printCell()

    // calc D3
    let D3 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "D3", cellName: "", value: D1.value + D2.value)
    D3ValueTextField.text = String(D3.value)
    D3.printCell()

   Cell.saveCellsUserDefaults(cells: [D1, D2, D3])

    // Calc D4 = D2 + D3

    let D4 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "D4", cellName: "", value: D1.value + D2.value)
    D4ValueTextField.text = String(D4.value)
    D4.printCell()




}
```

// In Cell class:

```
 static func saveCellsUserDefaults(cells: [Cell])  {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(cells) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(encoded, forKey: "pack")
    }
}


 static func getCellsUserDefaults()-> [Cell] {
    var cells = [Cell]()
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let cellData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "pack") {
        if let cellX = try? decoder.decode([Cell].self, from: cellData) {
            cells = cellX
            return cellX
        }
    }
    return cells
}
```

[image: MainViewController]

[image: SecondViewController]

**strong text**

Comment: show what `saveCellsUserDefaults` is doing and how you are populating data in Second VC

Comment: Done above, I hope you can see it ok

Comment: didn't see any code that set `D5ValueTextField`. But it looks like in second VC you are resetting your values saved in `UserDefaults`. you should use a different key (pack2) to save second VC values

Comment: D5 is set when user fills the TextField with a number and presses calc button, so then there is the action func calc () in SecondTableViewController which creates the object. The procedure is the same as in MainTableViewController, but there it works ok, that is the issue, thanks

Comment: You are setting C4 there `C4ValueTextField.text = String(C4.value)`. How you can expect it to fill without assigning a value to it?

Comment: Sorry, I do see the value in C4 in MainTableViewController. value = C1.value + C2.value and it is being represented on screen OK, both the first time VC is loaded and any other time you load that VC

Comment: https://github.com/FCh99/Hidraulica2Pruebas please have a look in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace your viewDidLoad method with following code,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // llamar a UD y sacar todos los packs por pantalla ???????
    var cells = Cell.getCellsUserDefaults(forKey: "pack")

    // calc D1
    let D1 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "D1", cellName: "", value: cells[0].value)
    D1ValueTextField.text = String(D1.value)
    //D1.printCell()

    // calc D2
    let D2 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "D2", cellName: "", value: cells[1].value)
    D2ValueTextField.text = String(D2.value)
    //D2.printCell()

    // calc D3 = D1 + D2
    let D3 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "D3", cellName: "", value: D1.value + D2.value)
    D3ValueTextField.text = String(D3.value)
    //D3.printCell()

    Cell.saveCellsUserDefaults(cells: [D1, D2, D3], forKey: "pack")

    var pack2Cells = Cell.getCellsUserDefaults(forKey: "pack2")
    let D5 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "D5", cellName: "", value: pack2Cells.isEmpty ? 0 : pack2Cells[0].value)
    D5ValueTextField.text = String(D5.value)
}
```

But remember that you need to click on calc first before going back to FirstViewContoller otherwise value in textfield won't persist.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding following line inside SecondViewController's viewDidLoad and then check,

```
let D5 = Cell(sheet: "In", colRowName: "D5", cellName: "", value: cells[4].value)
D5ValueTextField.text = String(D5.value)
```

Comment: It is not working, I send you the full code if you can work it out great   https://github.com/FCh99/Hidraulica2Pruebas

Comment: @FaustoCheca I have checked your code, it seems to be working fine. I mean cell D5 on second controller is getting value all the time. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I think it does not work. If you go to D5 and put 100 as input value, then return and next, you don´t see the 100 number